# Can't Run My App on My Android Phone

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

When the first time I run my app, it could run on my android phone (my phone is LG G2). but because I'm developing my app on eclipse, I often run on my LG G2 directly. but now my app can not run on my phone. It's cause my phone not detected by the eclipse. I've been trying in all my port USB (Run on my andro phone -> connect your phone with usb cable to your pc) and I've been tried to change my USB cable but it's not working at all. the eclipse just detect the emulator I've made. please help me. because my app has a LBS so it must be run on andro phone to check it. >.<

the device that my eclipse detect only 04c07r78dece28c0 AVD Name : N/A Target : Unknown and the State : Offline

NB : sorry before for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In menu settings, turn on your developer option setting, and in `Debbuging` option, check your USB debugging, if it still not working, re-install your USB mobile driver for your phone.

Comment: I've already re-installed it. After it was re-installed it can work perfectly, but again the eclipse didn't detect my phone. Once I restart both my pc and my phone, it can work. but now even I did the same, nothing's change. T.T. I even deleted my eclipse and using the new eclipse (ADT).

Comment: @user3673228 woghhhh you don't nedd to delete your eclipse, honestly, I am using your phone type too for develop my apps, in usb connection you must to choose charge phone not mtp, if it still not detect, first you must to check is your phone detect in your windows explore, if it detected, it will detect on your eclipse too.

Comment: it already detected on windows explorer.. So I thought that my eclipse which was wrong.. :D. could it be because of my windows?

Comment: what's the meaning of 'accept it as answer question" ? I've been reading that so many... hehehe I don't understand...

Comment: @user3673228 hehehehe beside my answer, there's button up and button down between '0' if you feel my answer usefull you can vote up my answer. and below button down vote, there is button checklist, if you feel my answer can help you, you can accept it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

In ur android device, u have to enable developer option in settings, Otherwise it wont detect.

Comment: I already activate USB Debugging and checklist the checkbox. but it's not working.

Comment: Which operating system ur using?

Comment: I'm using windows 7 home basic 64 bit,,

Comment: Just try to update  your usb driver. "http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html"